# Detatch Virtual Desktops in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop, projector

I can't seem to find a good answer on this so maybe someone out there has a solution. I use multiple desktops and I will be running an event where my Windows 10 machine will be hooked up to a projector. I want to assign the full screen application to a desktop on the projector, but I know that I will be using multiple Virtual Desktops while running the event, but I want the projector/monitor to always stay locked to *that* Virtual Desktop. Is this possible in Windows 10? I know in OSX it's possible.

So to recap:

**Monitor 1** - swapping between multiple virtual desktops
 
**Monitor 2** (projector) - locked on 1 virtual desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Windows 10 November Update, right-clicking a window in the Win+Tab view will show a context menu with the option to show it on all virtual desktops. This is not perfect, but it might be an acceptable solution for you.

Comment: This should actually work for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you! I did not realize this was an option. Microsoft, if you're out there, it would still be nice to be able to detach these desktops :-)